# API response data is null out of function angular 5

Tags: json, angular5, angular-components

Please find code below for better understanding

part-info-component.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormArray, Validators, FormBuilder, NgForm } 
   from '@angular/forms';
    import { CustomValidators } from '../../directives/custom-validator.directive';
    import { logbaseService } from "../../services/logbase.service";

    @Component({
    selector: 'app-part-info',
    templateUrl: './part-info.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./part-info.component.css']
    })
    export class PartInfoComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() partInfoData: string;
    partInfo: any = null;
    partInfoForm: FormGroup;

    partNumber: FormControl;
    followingProcess: FormControl;
    deliveryPoint: FormControl;
    partWeight: FormControl;
    partMaterial: FormControl;
    creationDate: FormControl;
    changeDate: FormControl;
    predecessorNo: FormControl;
    lotsSize: FormControl;
    partClassification: FormControl;
    width: FormControl;
    length: FormControl;
    height: FormControl;
    status: FormControl;

    constructor(private form: FormBuilder, private logBaseService: logbaseService) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllProductInfo();
    this.createFormControls();
    this.createForm();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.partInfo));
    };

    getAllProductInfo() {
    this.logBaseService.getPartsInfoAPI()
    .subscribe(
      data => this.partInfo = data.partInfo, // data is available only here
      error => console.log('Server Error')
    )
    }

    createFormControls() {
    this.partInfoForm = new FormGroup({
      partNumber: new FormControl(),
      partName: new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: true }),
      followingProcess: new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: true }),
      deliveryPoint: new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: true }),
      partWeight: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      partMaterial: new FormControl(),
      creationDate: new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: true }),
      changeDate: new FormControl(),
      predecessorNo: new FormControl(),
      lotsSize: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      partClassification: new FormControl(),
      width: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      length: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      height: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      status: new FormControl()
    });
    };

    createForm() {
    // this.partInfoForm = new FormGroup({
    //   partNumber: this.partInfoData.partNumber
    // });
    }

    saveForm(partInfoForm: NgForm) {

    console.log('Form saved successfully.');
    console.log(partInfoForm.value);
    }
    }
```

Here getAllProductInfo() will call service API to get all data from json file. Which is working fine.

And the response data is available inside getAllProductInfo()  function only. When i try to console.log it is showing as null.

Please let me know how to make the response data available through out the component. If you require any other details please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the working of application is asynchronous.
You have made the call and before getting the response you are reading the variable in another method.

Solution for this is. Add Promise and wait till the webservice returns you the response.
Once you receive response, continue with your business logic .

Comment: Is adding promise is only solution for this issue, or do we have any recommended way of fixing this issue.

Comment: I mostly used promise and got many tutorials which used promise to wait for webservice response and after it gets resolved then proceed for your business logic.